# How to use CASE statement once for multiple columns when the condition is identical?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, case

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN subject = '' THEN $subject ELSE subject END ) main_subject,
       (CASE WHEN subject = '' THEN $id ELSE id END ) main_id,
       (CASE WHEN subject = '' THEN $related ELSE related END ) main_related
FROM qanda
WHERE tag = :tag;
```

As  you see, the condition is identical in all conditions .. So I want to know, can I improve that? I mean can I write `CASE` just one time for all cases?

Comment: You have done it correctly.

Comment: Why would you want to have duplicate rows in your result for every row in the table with `subject = ''`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I don't have any duplicate row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine.  If you really wanted to, you could do:

```
SELECT $subject as main_subject, $id as main_id, $related as main_related
FROM qanda
WHERE tag = :tag AND subject = ''
UNION ALL
SELECT subject as main_subject, id as main_id, related as main_related
FROM qanda
WHERE tag = :tag AND (subject <> '' or subject IS NULL)
```

This gets rid of the `CASE` statements, but I don't think it is a real simplification.  It does, however, reduce the number of times that the condition needs to be copied, which can be a simplification if you have lots of columns.

Comment: Just one thing. as you know, the first `SELECT` statement of your query, doesn't select anything of `qanda` table, so why `FROM qanda`? I guess you can use `FROM dual`. Am I right?

Comment: @stack no, it is not the same. In this (and your) query, you get a row with your default values for each row that has an `subject = 0`, so anything between 0 and n, depending on `quanda`, that's why you need `from quanda`. Using `dual` will add your defaults exactly 1 time, no matter what.